# Prove Θ(n) + O(n^2) ≠ Θ(n^2)

Tags: big-o

How would I go about proving this statement?

```
Θ(n) + O(n^2) ≠ Θ(n^2)
```

I know how to prove if given a function f(n) if it's big o but I do not understand how to go about this type of problem.

Comment: The way you go about this problem is to reason from the definitions for big-O and big-Theta. Were specifically are you having trouble?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a specific programming problem or algorithm, but may do better on [Computer Science SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to find functions f and g such that

- f(n) = Θ(n),
- g(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>), but
- f(n) + g(n) ≠ Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

This establishes the result you're looking for by showing that the set of functions on the left-hand side of the equality isn't the same set of functions on the right-hand side of the equality.